# Kubernetes - Laravel Deployment on AWS gives "404 Not Found nginx/1.25.1"

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx

I'm having trouble deploying my Laravel application on AWS using Kubernetes. My setup includes a PHP-FPM Laravel application and Nginx in separate containers. However, when I try to access my application, I get a "404 Not Found nginx/1.25.1" error.

The 404 error is coming from Nginx, which suggests that the Nginx service is reachable but can't find the resource I'm asking for. I have specified the root directory in my `nginx.conf` file as `/var/www/html/public`, and my Laravel application files are located in `/var/www/html` in the `PHP-FPM` container.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Checked the logs for both the Nginx and PHP-FPM pods. Didn't find any errors related to the 404 issue.
Executed into a PHP-FPM pod and verified the Laravel application files are in the expected directory `(/var/www/html)`.
Made sure I delete and recreate the relevant Kubernetes resources after each change, to ensure the new configurations are used.
I've been working on this for several days but haven't made any progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the Kubernetes configuration that I've used:

```
# Base image
FROM php:8.1.0-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    g++ \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd zip intl mysqli pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable opcache

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Copy application files
COPY . .

# Copy .env.example to .env
COPY .env.example .env

# Install PHP dependencies
RUN composer install --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-plugins --prefer-dist

# Create storage and bootstrap/cache directories
RUN mkdir -p storage/framework/sessions storage/framework/views storage/framework/cache/data
RUN mkdir -p bootstrap/cache

# Set permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data storage bootstrap
RUN chmod -R 775 storage bootstrap

# Clear and cache config
RUN php artisan config:clear
RUN php artisan config:cache

# Expose port 9000
EXPOSE 9000

# Start PHP-FPM
CMD php artisan key:generate; php-fpm
```

deployment and nginx

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: web-server-config
  namespace: pep-system
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php index.html;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        root /var/www/html/public;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

            fastcgi_pass pep-web-svc:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                gzip_static on;
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: php-config
  namespace: pep-system
data:
  laravel.ini: |
    upload_max_filesize: 80M
    post_max_size: 80M
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pep-web
  namespace: pep-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pep-web
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pep-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pep-web
        image: myimage
        volumeMounts:
        - name: php-config
          mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/laravel.ini
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        resources:   
          requests: 
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 256Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 400m
            memory: 512Mi
        env:
        - name: DB_CONNECTION
          value: "mysql"
        - name: DB_HOST
          value: "database.cj3.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
        - name: DB_PORT
          value: "3306"
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: "pdb"
        - name: DB_USERNAME
          value: "admin"
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: "hap"
      volumes:
        - name: php-config
          configMap:
            name: php-config

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: pep-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        env:
        - name: PHP_FPM_SERVICE_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: web-server-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d/
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
        - name: web-server-config
          configMap:
            name: web-server-config 

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  web-server-svc
  namespace: pep-system
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app:  nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port:  80
    targetPort:  80
    nodePort: 32420
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  pep-web-svc
  namespace: pep-system
  labels:
    app: pep-web
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app:  pep-web
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port:  9000
```